# Scan though directory of files and find replicates with same name and concatenate them into one file

Tags: filenames, merge, file-management

I have a directory with a bunch of files

For example:

```
ExperimentA_Rep1.bed  
ExperimentA_Rep2.bed
ExperimentA_Rep3.bed 
ExperimentB_Rep1.bed 
ExperimentD_Rep1.bed 
ExperimentC_Rep1.bed
ExperimentC_Rep2.bed
 . . . 
ExperimentZ_Rep5.bed
```

I need to scan through the filenames in a directory and concatenate the files that are from the same experiment, but different replicates, into a new file.

I.e, `cat ExperimentA_Rep1.bed ExperimentA_Rep2.bed > ExperimentA_merged.bed`

But I can't hardcode this, it needs to be applicable for any dataset of experiments.

If I ran a python script that would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that the Rep portion of the filename is numbered sequentially from 1 (i.e. there won't be a Rep2 or Rep3 unless there is also a Rep1).  It uses the presence of a "Rep1" file to decide whether or not to run the cat for a particular series of Experiment* files...this is only necessary if there may be some files missing in the sequence ExperimentA* .. ExperimentZ*.  If that's not possible then just delete `[ -e Experiment${f}_Rep1.bed ] &&` from the cat line.

```
for f in {A..Z} ; do
    [ -e Experiment${f}_Rep1.bed ] && cat Experiment${f}_Rep*.bed > Experiment${f}_merged.bed
done
```